# Hamiltonian differential equation involving complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation
$$\begin{pmatrix}\dot p \\ \dot q \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{p^2+q^2}\begin{pmatrix} p \\ q \end{pmatrix}$$
where $(p,q)^T\in \mathbb R ^2 - \{0\}$. I want to show that this differential equation is Hamiltonian with Hamiltonian function $H(p,q)=-\operatorname{Im} (\log(p+iq))$ on any simply connected set $U\in \mathbb R^2 -\{0\}$.

I know that on any simply connected complex domain we can define a logarithm. However I am stuck on calculating its derivatives with respect to $p$ and $q$. (This is not homework.)

*Edit:*
We have
\begin{align*}
-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}(p,q) &=-\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\left\{ -\operatorname{Im} (\log(p+iq))\right\} \\
&=\operatorname{Im}\frac{\partial \log}{\partial q}(p+iq) \\
&=\operatorname{Im} i \log'(p+iq) \\
&=\operatorname{Im} \frac{i}{p+iq} \\
&=\frac{p}{p^2+q^2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

By setting $z(t) = p(t)+i q(t)$ DE can be written as:
$$ z'(t) = \frac{1}{p(t)-i q(t)} = \frac{1}{\overline{z(t)}} $$
and I think you can get it from here: $\log(z)$ is a primitive of $\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I don't see how to proceed from your hint. I have updated my question with a calculation.